# How to find out which code is using Sendmail?

Tags: php, linux, sendmail

We are having some unknown code (virus?) sending out thousands of mails from our server suddenly and though we think we have removed the corresponding malicious PHP file, the mails are still getting sent out.

How can I find out which code is sending out the mails? I tried looking under /var/log/maillog but no pointers there. Any other way of finding it out?

We are using CentOS distro.

Comment: What makes you think it is PHP sending the mail? As opposed to say a shell script, or other executable?

Comment: It is possible that a shell script or other executable might be sending this, but the admin who looked into this said he has removed the malicious PHP file that existed for one of our sites. 

That's exactly the reason I want to know which code is sending out those mails.

Comment: Are you sure that the emails are *originating* from your sever? Could someone be sending emails to people and simply placing your server as the sender? You said that you found no "pointers" in your `maillog`, but do the emails sent actually appear there?

Comment: @Lix - mails are indeed getting sent from our server. "mailq" shows tons of bouncing emails (typical Viagra and all that spam) maillog is showing those mails as well, but no pointer to let me know which code might be sending those mails.

Comment: Any more pointers here? We haven't been able to fix this problem yet! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The malicious code was in Wordpress DB and associated PHP files, every time site was getting loaded - it was called with call to header PHP. We cleaned the site and fresh install fixed the problem. I had already checked crontab and there was no infected code there. Thanks for all the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have removed the corresponding PHP file doesn't mean that that file didn't manage to make copies of itself elsewhere on your system. If you say that these emails are being sent continuously, ie. this was not a single occurance, then it is possible that the script has somehow infiltrated your crontab files and is calling itself periodically.

Take a look at your crontab file for each user (including root) on your system. Make sure to inspect **any** script the crontab is executing no matter how innocent it looks.

---

Another option would be an `.htaccess` file executing a certain script when presented with a specific URL. One could easily hide the execution of a script in this way. Inspect all `.htaccess` files for strange rules that you have no record of...

---

Hopefully one or more of these options will shed some light on where these emails are being sent from...

Comment: This could be useful. Let me check that out.

Comment: Nothing suspicious in either cron jobs or .htaccess (though we didn't check this file for every directory.

We are suspecting corrupt DB and some bad/infected Wordpress plugin now.